# tda-api assigning streaming endpoints to variables

Tags: python, variables, python-asyncio, endpoint

I am new to pyhton APIs. I can not get the script to return a value. Could anyone give me a direction please. I can not get the lambda function to work properly. I am trying to save the streamed data into variables to use with a set of operations.

```
from tda.auth import easy_client
from tda.client import Client
from tda.streaming import StreamClient

import asyncio
import json

import config
import pathlib
import math
import pandas as pd

client = easy_client(
        api_key=config.API_KEY,
        redirect_uri=config.REDIRECT_URI,
        token_path=config.TOKEN_PATH)
stream_client = StreamClient(client, account_id=config.ACCOUNT_ID)

async def read_stream():
        login = asyncio.create_task(stream_client.login()) 
        await login
        service = asyncio.create_task(stream_client.quality_of_service(StreamClient.QOSLevel.EXPRESS))
        await service

        book_snapshots = {}        

        def my_nasdaq_book_handler(msg):

                book_snapshots.update(msg)

                
        stream_client.add_nasdaq_book_handler(my_nasdaq_book_handler)

        stream = stream_client.nasdaq_book_subs(['GOOG','AAPL','FB'])
        await stream
        
        while True:
                await stream_client.handle_message()

                print(book_snapshots)               
                

asyncio.run(read_stream())
```

Comment: The example from [Streaming Client](https://tda-api.readthedocs.io/en/stable/streaming.html#streaming-client) is basically what you are showing us as your code. Did you read [Enabling Real-Time Data Access](https://tda-api.readthedocs.io/en/stable/streaming.html#enabling-real-time-data-access) as well? BTW: what Python version are you using?

Comment: Python3. 

And yes. I have no issues with streaming the data but I want to be able to handle the data as it comes in within the module to be passed through a series of operations. The literature does a poor job at explaining that. I have tried modifying the ascnyc function but I’m have failed to get it to work. I can’t figure out how to return a value from the lambda function. That’s really all I need from the script. Thank you for replying 

What would you recommend?

Comment: Also as I said I am new to APIs so I’m not sure if that can even be done or if that’s the correct or best way to go about that.

Comment: At least add the (significant) information you gave in comments to the question! Also to say "Python3" is not very informative because it's obvious. Be more specific please, use the 3-number format like 3.8.7 or 3.9.1 or ...

Comment: There’s no way to return a value from a lambda function. I thought everything was so obvious?? The script only lets you see things it does not let you pull information from it. I am trying to build triggers from the stream data.

Comment: Does it do `lambda msg: print(json.dumps(msg, indent=4))`? If yes you should be able to change the behavior. Again: please add the information bit's to the question, preferably in a way (structured and readable) that helps people to get an overview! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I understand that 'stream_client.login()' logs you in obvously.  'stream_client.quality_of_service(StreamClient.QOSLevel.EXPRESS)' specifies which service and responsivness that you are requesting. 'stream_client.add_nasdaq_book_handler()'  contains all the trade data. 'stream_client.nasdaq_book_subs(['FB','MSFT','AAPL'])'  specifies which stocks you would like to see out of all the trade data. I'm lost to where in 'read_stream()'  to return a variable which overwrites itself while the stream updates. The string you specified is in the script and executes fine.

Comment: please correct me if I misunderstood. From my understanding, its not possible to return a value from a lambda function because it is anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

### Callbacks

This (wrong) assumption

> `stream_client.add_nasdaq_book_handler()` contains all the trade data.

shows difficulties in understanding the [*callback*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) concept. Typically the naming pattern *add*  *handler* indicates that this concept is being used. There is also the comment in the boiler plate code from the [Streaming Client](https://tda-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/streaming.html) docs

```
 # Always add handlers before subscribing because many streams start sending
 # data immediately after success, and messages with no handlers are dropped.
```

that consistently talks about *subscribing* - also this word is a strong indicator.

The basic principle of a callback is that instead you *pull* the information from a service (and being blocked *until* it's available), you enable that service to *push* that information to you *when* it's available. You do this typically be first registering one (or more) interest(s) with the service and after then wait for the things to come.

In section [Handling Messages](https://tda-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/streaming.html#handling-messages) they give an example for function (to provide by you) as follows:

```
def sample_handler(msg):
    print(json.dumps(msg, indent=4))
```

which takes a `str` argument which is dumped in JSON format to the console. The `lambda` in your example does exactly the same.

### Lambdas

> it's not possible to return a value from a lambda function because it is anonymous

This is not correct. If lambda functions wouldn't be able to return values, they wouldn't play such an important role. See [4.7.6. Lambda Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) in the Python 3 docs.

The problem in your case is that both functions don't do anything you want, both just print to console. Now you need to get into these functions to tell what to do.

### Control

Actually, your program *runs* within this loop

```
while True:
    await stream_client.handle_message()
```

each `stream_client.handle_message()` call finally causes a call to the function you registered by calling `stream_client.add_nasdaq_book_handler`. So that's the point: your script defines what to do when messages arrive *before* it gets waiting.

For example, *your* function could just collect the arriving messages:

```
book_snapshots = []

def my_nasdaq_book_handler(msg):
    book_snapshots.append(msg)
```

A global object `book_snapshots` is used in the implementation. You may expand/change this function at will (of course translating the information into JSON format will help you accessing it in a structured way). This line will register your function:

```
stream_client.add_nasdaq_book_handler(my_nasdaq_book_handler)
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I updated the post. Do you have any suggestions? I have tried running several ASYNC functions with co routines so each function outputs one stock data set. I ran into some issues because of the login session so i though it would be more effeicent to handle all the data as a whole. I know there is a deeper answer for why the "for" statements run in my test.py file but not the stream. Thank you for your help this far.

Comment: Sorry, that's not how StackOverflow works. Please revert your edits in the question and ask a new question. ... and *please* take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I reverted it as best as i could remember the original post. however i have posted the modification in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66193081/issues-assigning-re-assigning-real-time-data-to-variables-using-asyncio-python

Comment: @Wolf I liked this answer, I wish I could accept it on behalf of OP